# WooCommerce - Stock in Decimals, Using Quantity Intervals with Unique Prices

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to implement the following in my store:

When someone purchases an item, it might take .5 of my stock. I also want to sell in quantity intervals with a set price for each interval. Having this set price is important because as they buy more, they will receive a discount.

For example:

1 meter = $10
2.5 meters = $20
5 meters = $40

I have looked everywhere for a plugin that will help me achieve this. Does anyone know of a combination of plugins or a workaround to make this happen?

Thanks!

Rose